# Can an Interface variable be reinitialised?

Tags: java, interface, static, final

```
interface abs{
 int a=10;// by default final static
     void callme(); 
}
class B implements abs{
    int a =11;// reinitializing

    void call()
    {
            System.out.println("No problem"+a);
    }
    public void callme()
    {
            System.out.println("Call me"+a);
    }

}
class main{


    public static void main(String args[]){

        B m=new B();
        m.call();
        m.callme();
    }

}
```

In Herbert Schildt book, I have read that the interface variables are default Final and static. Which implicitly means that it will act like a constant. but when I am assigning 11 in the variable a in my above mentioned code, it is not giving any error.

**o/p
No problem11
Call me11**

Comment: Your variable is not static, and if it were, it would just hide the final static field from the interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not re-initializing the variable, but you're *hiding* it.

In order to access `abs`'s `a` member, you have to refer it with the interface name. Something like:

```
System.out.println("No problem" + abs.a);
```

Comment: @user3053677: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared variable again

```
int a =11;
```

so see the error you want

do this in your class

```
a=11;
```

in your case the a is an entire new variable belonging to class B

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying the value of `abs.a` when you initialize `a` in class `B`. The field `B.a` simply hides the inherited `a` from the interface. You can still get to `abs.a` from code in class `B` by using the fully qualified name `abs.a`.

Answer (score 0):

***No, You can't reinitialize Interface variable.*** The variable in your Implementation Class is not interface variable A, but B class' instance variable. If you want to access Interface variable you reference it as `abs.A`

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is hiding the variable in interface by declaring a variable with same name in class B. You can verify it by using this code:

```
public interface Abs {
            int a=10;// by default final static
            void callme();
            default void printA() {
                System.out.println("A in interface: " + a);
            }
    }

public class B implements Abs {
    int a =11;// reinitializing

    void call()
    {
        System.out.println("A in class: "+a);
    }
    public void callme()
    {
        printA();
    }
}
```

Then we have:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        B m=new B();
        m.call();
        m.callme();
    }
```

It prints:

`A in class: 11
A in interface: 10`